# Telegram bot API sendPhoto / Documents | Java

Tags: java, api, bots, telegram

I want to make a simple Telegram Bot. It does not work out with method - sendPhoto (URL). When using the online command, the bot should send a picture to the user. The picture itself is dynamic, so I use sendPhoto URL.

Code:

```
public class SimpleBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApiContextInitializer.init();
    TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
    try {
        telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new SimpleBot());
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public String getBotUsername() {
    return "SavchukBot";
}

@Override
public String getBotToken() {
    return "TOKEN";
}

@Override
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    Message message = update.getMessage();
    if (message != null && message.hasText()) {
        if (message.getText().equals("/help"))
            sendMsg(message, "Test");

    }

    if (message != null && message.hasText()) {
        if (message.getText().equals("/команды"))
            sendMsg(message,  "TestV2.0");
    }

    if (message != null && message.hasText()) {
        if (message.getText().equals("/online"))
            sendImageFromUrl("http://samp-stats.ru/web/userbar-15377.png", "@SavchukBot" );


} }

public void sendImageFromUrl(String url, String chatId) {
    SendPhoto sendPhotoRequest = new SendPhoto();
    sendPhotoRequest.setChatId(chatId);
    sendPhotoRequest.setPhoto("http://samp-stats.ru/web/userbar-15377.png");
    try {
        sendPhoto(sendPhotoRequest);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}





private void sendMsg(Message message, String text) {
    SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
    sendMessage.enableMarkdown(true);
    sendMessage.setChatId(message.getChatId().toString());
    sendMessage.setReplyToMessageId(message.getMessageId());
    sendMessage.setText(text);
    try {
        sendMessage(sendMessage);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Errors that I get when running a command - /online:

```
org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException: Error sending photo: [400] Bad Request: chat not found
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.send.SendPhoto.deserializeResponse(SendPhoto.java:153)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.DefaultAbsSender.sendPhoto(DefaultAbsSender.java:210)
    at SimpleBot.sendImageFromUrl(SimpleBot.java:62)
    at SimpleBot.onUpdateReceived(SimpleBot.java:52)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:301)
```

Any thoughts how to solve this problem. Thank you =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter two `chatId` should be target chat ID, not bot name.

Try to pass `message.getChatId().toString()` as parameter.

Comment: There is a difference? This is what is said in API:
chat_id - Integer or String - Unique identifier for the target chat or username of the target channel (in the format @channelusername). Or I not so understand something?

Comment: It's target, not yourself